# How to send a generated token to an email for users to create a password through MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, email, access-token

So I'm creating a registration form on a website I'm developing, and I'm still new to MySQL and PHP. Now, part of a security promise I have for the website, I want it to be that when users register, it will send them a link to the user's email (much like a token) and, when they go to the email, they will be required to create a password after they click on the link in the email. Now, with the token, I want it to follow up as IP validation, so where the users register, they must continue registration with that same device. Pretty much, this is what I need it to be:
1. The users register on the website with an email, their full name, and a custom username.
2. The user will have to go to their email to complete the registration 'on the same device they just registered their account on'
3. The user clicks on the link and creates their password.
a. If the user is on the same device they registered with, it will continue to the create password form.
b. If the user is not on the same device they registered with, they will get an error page saying "This device cannot be used to login to this account as the IP address does not match the one when this account was first registered."

How can I do this? As I said, I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: Although making a token-validation system really isn't that hard, I would not recommend you to use IP adresses as a basis for something like this in this day and age. I had to cancel my plans for this as well after I found this out; A lot of cellphones use the same IP-address since they somewhat proxy on their providers... It makes some things quite difficult! However, doing IP validation on top of E-mail validation kind of seems like overkill to me? You could use their e-mail and password to strengthen your token encryption and make it unique to them, right?

Comment: This really is too broad. There's a lot of places to pull the pieces together out there on the Internet

Comment: @Babydead what about MAC authentication? Is that possible?

Comment: @MichaelAdamLowellWatne nope, you can't get to MAC addresses. Those are private.